# update current row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have searched everywhere for help with this, but can't seem to find the answer. I have a form where people can enter a search term. Upon clicking the submit button, it links to a PHP page that searches for the term entered against 3 fields in my DB. This is all working fine. I want to add a button to each result that is displayed that allows me to click to add to an incrementing number.

This is working if I define what row I want to update in my query statement as it redirects to itself once the button is clicked; but I want the button to update the record shown in the results rather than a defined record.

Obviously there can be several returned results each with its own button so I want the user to be able to click the button attached to that record and for it to update the field in that row of the DB.  Is it possible to define "current record" in any way?

Here is the current code:

```
if($_POST['like']){

$add =("UPDATE Players SET played=played+1 WHERE SquadNo=11");
$result = mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

As you can see I have defined `squad number 11` at this point, but want to update the current row.

The second problem, minor at this stage, is that when I click the button to increment the value, it seems to update the search and delivers a different set of results once the increment has occurred. How can I prevent this happening?

Thanks - and I hope this makes sense.

Here's my full code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "USER","PASSWORD")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("TABLE");

 if($_POST['like']){


    $add =("UPDATE Players SET played=played+1 WHERE SquadNo=11");
    $result = mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());

    }

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from Players where POS like '%$term%' or POS2 like '%$term%' or POS3 like '%$term%' ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'Name: '.$row['Name'];
    echo '<br/> Surname: '.$row['Surname'];
    echo '<br/> Position 1: '.$row['POS'];
    echo '<br/> Position 2: '.$row['POS2'];
    echo '<br/> Position 3: '.$row['POS3'];
    echo '<br/> Squad Number: '.$row['SquadNo'];
    echo '<br/> Played: '.$row['played'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo'<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]. '">
   <input type="submit" name="like" value="like"><br>
</form>';
      echo '<br/><br/>';

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of which row the button's on, e.g.

```
<form ...>
   <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="$row['record_id']" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then do the equivalent of

```
UDPATE yourtable SET ... WHERE row_id = $row_id_from_form
```

Comment: Hidden fields are very useful in these cases, that way each record is linked to a certain `rowId` for each row being displayed

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this @MarcB and everyone else, really appreciate it.  I can see how this works and the theory behind it, but I think my poor execution id preventing it from working. The number isn't incrementing but it is updating the page, have I done something wrong?  echo'<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]. '">
   <input type="submit" name="played" value="played"><br>
   <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
</form>';

Comment: code for incrementing is in the same place as that above and is



 if($_POST['played']){
  $rowid = $_POST['rowID'];
    $add =("UPDATE Players SET played=played+1 WHERE SquadNo='.$rowid.'");
    $result = mysql_query($add) or die(mysql_error());
 
 }

Comment: if it's not working, then first step is to 'view source' in your browser, see if the generated html looks ok - make sure those row IDs are showing up in the form. then on the php side, do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's coming across. html glitches can kill/mangle form submissions. then just keep digging deeper into the code.